# How to restrict drag-drop action to one app

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

I am adding storage items to DataPackage when UIElement drag starts, but the problem is if I drag it to other apps or to Windows desktop, Windows interferes with drop action. Is there any way I can restrict the DataPackage to be only read by my app??

Comment: Hi, can you explain what exactly is `Windows interferes`? If you can provide the code, it will be more helpful to analyze the problem.

Comment: I am designing a tabbed editor app. I want to create a new instance of the app when I drag a tab outside of the app. The problem I have is whenever I am dragging it to my desktop, system detects is as a file and provides a context menu for copy/move/create shortcut. I have to cancel the context menu to have my desired effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In UWP, you can write data to `DragItemsStartingEventArgs.Data` in the `DragItemsStarting` event. You are writing `StorageItem`. When dragging to the desktop, the system will call the corresponding default processing method. This behavior is a system behavior, and the UWP application cannot prevent it.

If your purpose is just to drag the tab and create a new window, you don’t need to write data to `DataPackage`, just let it be processed inside the application, and listen to the `DragItemsCompleted` event.

```cs
private void Tabs_DragItemsStarting(object sender, DragItemsStartingEventArgs e)
{
    //get file
    e.Items.Add(myFile);
}

private void Tabs_DragItemsCompleted(ListViewBase sender, DragItemsCompletedEventArgs args)
{
    var items = args.Items;
    if (items.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            if(item is StorageFile file)
            {
                // create new window
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If the data is written to `DataPackage`, it means that the party that obtains the data processes the data (such as a desktop or other software), and this process application cannot interfere.

Thanks.

Comment: I have changed my method to add StorageItem to e.Data.Properties.Add("token", myFile), since I am also using drag and drop between different app instances. I no longer have to deal with system detecting dragged item as StorageItem. But dragging over some programs like VS Code and Firefox still fails to create a new instance.

Comment: Hi, Do you want to create an instance of VSCode or Firefox? If it is, then this cannot be solved from UWP, because UWP applications cannot interfere with the internal processing of other applications. If not, can you show the code for creating an application instance?

Comment: No, what I want is normal tab drag and drop behavior for example browsers have. When I drop the tab in another instance of the app it moves the tab to other instance and I have achieved it in my code. The problem is I want to create a new instance of the app if I drop the tab anywhere but another instance of the app. If for example the background app is firefox/vs code dropping tab on them should create new instance of my app but this doesn't happen.

Comment: Hi, Drag an element to another instance of the application, you can listen to Drop-related events in that instance, and to handle the situation of dragging to other applications, because you can not listen to the Drop events of other applications, you need to be in your own application Handled in the `DragItemsCompleted` event. Can I know how you currently process this event? please provide the code in this event so that I can help you better.